# SwiftUI Widget not rendering API data

Tags: swift, swiftui, ioswidgets

I'm creating a Widget working with an API, but when I ran it, it consolelogged me all the data (from the fetch call), but on the screen, inside the widget, nothing appears. I'm new to WidgetKit so it's maybe something easy, idk :).

Everything I'm making is to call the api, and retriving the data into a Model, and since here, everything it's okay. The main problem is that when i load the widget, inside it still remain the "3" that comes from and else on the api data... kinda stressed about it, since I don't know where to start acutally... I'll share the code!

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

struct WelcomeTeamWidget: Decodable, Equatable {
    let fixtures: FixturesTeam?
    
    static func == (lhs: WelcomeTeamWidget, rhs: WelcomeTeamWidget) -> Bool {
        lhs.fixtures == rhs.fixtures
    }
}
struct FixturesTeam: Decodable, Equatable {
    let allFixtures: AllFixturesTeam?
    struct AllFixturesTeam: Decodable {
        let nextMatch: MatchWidget?
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: FixturesTeam, rhs: FixturesTeam) -> Bool {
        lhs.allFixtures?.nextMatch?.id == rhs.allFixtures?.nextMatch?.id
    }
}

struct MatchWidget: Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let leagueId: Int?
    let time: String?
    let home: TeamWidget?
    let away: TeamWidget?
    let eliminatedTeamId: Int?
    let statusId: Int?
    let tournamentStage: String?
    let status: MatchStatusWidget?
    let timeTS: TimeInterval?
    let finished: Bool?
    let started: Bool?
    let cancelled: Bool?
    let scoreStr: String?
    let tournament: TournamentWidget?

    struct TeamWidget: Decodable {
        let id: Int?
        let score: Int?
        let name: String?
        let longName: String?
    }
}

struct TournamentWidget: Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
    let parentLeagueId: Int?
    let link: String?
    let leagueName: String?
    let roundName: String?
    let round: String?
    let selectedSeason: String?
    let isCurrentSeason: Bool?
}

struct MatchStatusWidget: Decodable {
    let utcTime: String?
    let started: Bool?
    let cancelled: Bool?
    let finished: Bool?
    let scoreStr: String?
    let liveTime: LiveTimeWidget?
}

struct LiveTimeWidget: Decodable {
    let short, shortKey, long, longKey: String?
    let maxTime, penalties, addedTime: Int?
}


class TeamViewModelWidget: ObservableObject {
    @Published var welcomeTeamWidget: WelcomeTeamWidget?
    
    func fetchData() {
        let currentTimestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
        let apiUrl = "https://www.fotmob.com/api/teams?id=8636&ccode3=ITA&_=\(currentTimestamp)"
        
        if let url = URL(string: apiUrl) {
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WelcomeTeamWidget.self, from: data)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.welcomeTeamWidget = decodedData
                            print("Data fetched successfully: \(self.welcomeTeamWidget)")
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Error decoding data: \(error)")
                    }
                } else if let error = error {
                    print("Error fetching data: \(error)")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}

struct Provider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent())
    }

    func snapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration)
    }

    func timeline(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<SimpleEntry> {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration)
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        return Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent
}

struct BalunWidgetEntryView : View {
    @ObservedObject private var teamViewModelWidget = TeamViewModelWidget()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(Color.widgetBackground)
            
            VStack {
                if let widgetData = teamViewModelWidget.welcomeTeamWidget {
                    if let homeTeamName = widgetData.fixtures?.allFixtures?.nextMatch?.home?.name {
                        Text("\(homeTeamName)")
                            .font(.system(size: 15)).foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                    } else {
                        Text("2")
                            .font(.system(size: 15)).foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("3")
                        .font(.system(size: 15)).foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: teamViewModelWidget.welcomeTeamWidget) { newValue in WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
            }
            .onAppear {
                teamViewModelWidget.fetchData()
            }
        }
        
    }

    private func refreshUI() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.teamViewModelWidget.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}

extension WidgetConfiguration {
    func disableContentMarginsIfNeeded() -> some WidgetConfiguration {
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *) {
            return self.contentMarginsDisabled()
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}

struct BalunWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "Balun Widget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationAppIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            BalunWidgetEntryView()
                .containerBackground(.fill.tertiary, for: .widget)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("That's a Balun Widget")
        .description("And no one can say a shit about it")
        .disableContentMarginsIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know much about widget, but have you tried using `@StateObject private var teamViewModelWidget = TeamViewModelWidget()` in your `BalunWidgetEntryView`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine yes, but yet the problem still the same...

Comment: I have a hunch that this has to do with the asynchronous fetching of the data. I would try fetching the data synchronously, and, perhaps passing it into the widget view as a part of a `TimelineEntry`.

Comment: This is not how `Widgets` work. These are static views. Take a look at the [example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension/) from Apple. You basicly create the data to present in the widget while you create your timeline. If you want to know how to use async code inside the `TimelineProvider` take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73448238/6950415) here.